# How do I write condition in polymer1.0 with "dom-if"?

Tags: if-statement, polymer

I have below code:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{item.hasAttach}}">
     <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i>
</template>
```

**item.hasAttach = true/false**

But I want to check condition in this if like : 
**item.content_format_code == 'PDF'**

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{item.content_format_code == 'PDF'}}">
         <i class="fa fa-pdf"></i>
    </template>
<template is="dom-if" if="{{item.content_format_code == 'JPEG'}}">
         <i class="fa fa-jpg"></i>
    </template>
<template is="dom-if" if="{{item.content_format_code == 'xls'}}">
         <i class="fa fa-xls"></i>
    </template>
```

it should be like **{{item.content_format_code == 'PDF'}} = true/false**
But it is not testing this.
I want to show icon as per file type. *item.content_format_code == 'PDF'* this is not checked *true/false*. In polymer it takes only true/false as a conditional actual value but don't check expression. 
Please Help me.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed).

Define a function that computes the expression and bind it to the `dom-if`.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[isFormat(item.content_format_code, 'PDF')]]">
     <i class="fa fa-pdf"></i>
</template>

Polymer({
    is: "my-element",
    isFormat: function(code, format) {
        return code === format;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Maria thanks for the reply it really helped me. What to write if I have 20 conditions it will increase the code. I don't want code to be lengthy. I want to optimize the code. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi @Ravi. I have updated my answer. You can pass in a string literal (for example `'PDF'`) as an argument to you function.

Answer (score 10):

Currently, polymer only supports simple constructs for conditions. This means that you can't write something like

```
[[ item.something == 'CONDITION' ]]
```

You are left with 2 choices:

1. The item used for the condition is a boolean, than simply writing

   ```
   [[ item ]]
   ```

   or

   ```
   [[ !item ]]
   ```

   will work. The only operator you can use is '!'
2. With more complex conditions, [use computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed):

   ```
   [[ _computeResult(item) ]]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar and if you have access to your data it is much easier to just have a list of booleans like "is-PDF, is-JPG, is-PNG". Then you can just do;

```html
<template is="dom-if" if="[[item.is-PDF]]">
```

That is what I ended up doing.