# polymer templates repeating in dom-if

Tags: polymer-1.0

Changed to make it more clear.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{survey.Questions}}">
  <template is="dom-if" restamp if="{{isFormat(item.Type, 'Single-Select')}}">
    <question-singleselect question="{{item}}" auth-Data="{{authData}}"></question-singleselect>
  </template>
  <template is="dom-if" restamp if="{{isFormat(item.Type,'Open-Ended'}}">
    <question-openended question="{{item}}" auth-Data="{{authData}}"></question-openended>
  </template>
  <template is="dom-if" restamp if="{{isFormat(item.Type,'Text Block'}}">
    <question-textblock question="{{item}}" auth-Data="{{authData}}"></question-textblock>
  </template>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{[[}}isFormat(item.Type,'Numerical'}}">
    D: {{item.Type}}
    <question-numerical question="{{item}}" auth-Data="{{authData}}"></question-numerical>
  </template>
</template>
```

Here is my code with your function added, which set's it to true or false.

I have one type, for each of the element listed above, so an array of 4 records.

The results show the records from the array, but the above templates with the dom-if show each record in each element. For instance, the data that has type of numerical, will show up in each section shown above, and not hide them.

In the questions object, we have different types of questions in the survey, but when we pass in the survey object, the question is repeated in the different formats that are in the different question template types... that is....question one will show under both question type 1 (say a radio button) and question type 2, (say checkboxes), even though it is listed as type1 in the json that is returned in survey.

Am I using the dom-repeat and dom-if correctly? Wonder what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer doesn't support expressions in bindings. See also [How do I write condition in polymer1.0 with "dom-if"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069770/how-do-i-write-condition-in-polymer1-0-with-dom-if)

`dom-repeat` is fine I guess from what can be said without seeing the code.

Comment: Your fix was right, bu if you see my updated code above, I am missing a right parenthesis, doesn't come up in any debugger or linter, or anything like that....so that kind of sucks that these simple typoes don't show up.

Comment: I see. I don't know about plans about linters or similar. I'm not too involved in Polymer currently.